# how to not use compare_length_with

Tags: javascript

I have this code and I don't understand the `compare_length_with` function so I'd like to rewrite this code without this function

```
let rec blast list =
  let cmp = List.compare_length_with list 2 in
  if cmp = 0 then
    List.hd list
  else if cmp > 0 then
    blast (List.tl list)
  else
    failwith "not"
```

I read that

> `compare_length_with l n` is equivalent to `compare (length l) n`

But I struggle to make it work.

Comment: It might help if you told us 'exactly' what this function does.

Comment: Please edit your question and define what you want from your function and what problems do you have. Answering your question directly: `compare_length_with xs n` returns `-1`, `0`, or `1` if the length of the list `xs` is less than, equal, or greater than `n`.

Comment: @G4143 I updated my post. This code find the penultimate number in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `List.compare_length_with` compares the list length with the provided number. As any other `compare` function in OCaml it is a three-value comparison that immediately tells you whether one of the two compared values is less than, equal, or greater than the other. For example, `compare 0 1` is `-1` and `compare 1 1` is `0`, finally `compare 1 0` is `1`. The `List.compare_length_with` function takes the list as its first argument and compares its length with the second argument, using the regular compare function. Nothing fancy here.  Using regular comparison operators (`<`, `>`, `<=`, etc), you can obtain the same information but it will require you to do a couple of comparisons and if/then/else expressions. This all good to know, but is totally not required for your task, in which you can certainly use the regular comparison. E.g., `List.length xs = 2` will be true when `xs` contains two elements, so the following will return the penultimate number

```
(* you will be get the least possible grade for such function *)
let rec bad_penultimate xs = 
   if List.length xs = 2 then List.hd xs 
   else bad_penultimate (List.tl xs)
```

This function is rather non-idiomatic and runs in a quadratic time, i.e., for a list of length N it will make O(N^2) list element traverses. It is also doing the same as your `bforelast` but a little bit more concise.

To write a better function we shall use pattern-matching and notice that a list of length 2 will always match with the pattern `[_ ; _]` and in order to learn whether a list has 2 elements we don't need to go through the whole list and compute its full length. I am leaving you it as an exercise to devise a good penultimate function. Hint, there shall not be any `List` module functions in it and even no if/then/else expressions. Try to do it with pattern-matching only.